# Continue running on remote linux server in an conda environment

Tags: shell-script, ssh, nohup

I am working in a conda environment and want to keep running after my disconnect. Normally,  I use nohup for this purpose but is it possible to use nohup in a conda environment?

`nohup bash program.sh` Is this command works? Or how to proceed?

Comment: have you tried ? if available `screen` might be a better option (you can disconnect and reconnect later).

Comment: Actually the program runs about 20 hours and I am in hurry and don't wanna an error after 15 hours. it seems running but I am not sure about what is the state of conda environment. How can I use screen command. Like `screen bash program.sh`?